# Failed to load favicon

Tags: angular

I'm pretty new to Angular. I just started by creating a new "hello world" application.

Anyway, when I executed `ng serve` and went to my app at localhost:4200, I noticed there was no favicon.

I'm getting the following error in the Chrome console:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

The icon is being served (if I go to `localhost:4200/favicon.ico`, I can see that the file exists and is there), but for some reason Chrome is not showing it:

[image: Favicon exists in the server]

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: do you have add blocker in you browser? AdBlock blocks the page and throws a ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT error.

Comment: That was easy haha! Seems that AB was blocking it. Thanks @ZearaeZ.

Comment: You must wellcome. Please dont forget to mark as answer in comment. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you have some AdBlocker in your browser. AdBlock blocks the page and throws a ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT error. Disable this AdBlocker may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to allow your url/domain from blocked security (proxy settings) of browser. Please refer below links:

https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-solve-err-blocked-by-client/
https://www.techinpost.com/fixed-error-err_blocked_by_client-code-problem-instantly/